# regex to bring a word inside a quoted substring

Tags: python, regex, double-quotes

I am working on a function that works by identifying if `LP` or `LLP` appear, preceded or not by a space, after a `"` at any position in the string. If this is the case i'd like to bring the  `LP` or `LLP` sub string inside the quoted sub string, as shown below.

```
# input
'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY ONE "LLP blabla'
'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY TWO " LLP blabla'
'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY THREE " LP blabla'
'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY FOUR "LP blabla'

# output
'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY ONE LLP" blabla'
'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY TWO LLP" blabla'
'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY THREE LP" blabla'
'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY FOUR LP" blabla'
```

So far, I got to this function, which almost does what I want:

```
def fix_entity_broken_by_quotes(text):

    match = r'"\s*(LL?P)'
    replace = r'" \1 "'

    return ' '.join(re.sub(match, replace, text).split())

# run

>>> fix_entity_broken_by_quotes('blabla "RANDOM COMPANY ONE" LLP blabla')
Out[1]: 'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY ONE" LLP " blabla'
```

I would not want the `"` after `ONE` in the resulting string.

As always, any hint or explanation on what I am missing is very welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*hint or explanation on what I am missing is very welcome.*
You have leading `"` in your `replace`

```
match = r'"\s*(LL?P)'
replace = r'" \1 "'
```

Changing `replace` to `r' \1 "'` should help.

Comment: Oh!! I see - the leading " was added by me! Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `re.sub`:

```py
inp = ['blabla "RANDOM COMPANY ONE "LLP blabla', 'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY TWO " LLP blabla', 'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY THREE " LP blabla', 'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY FOUR "LP blabla']
output = [re.sub(r'"[ ]?(LP|LLP)', r'\1"', x) for x in inp]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['blabla "RANDOM COMPANY ONE LLP" blabla',
 'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY TWO LLP" blabla',
 'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY THREE LP" blabla',
 'blabla "RANDOM COMPANY FOUR LP" blabla']
```